# Lie algebra and Lie group irreps

Tags: lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra, we can get Lie group my exponential map. My question is, is there a relationship between the irreps of the Lie algebra and the corresponding lie group by the exponential map?

Comment: In fact, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519210/relation-between-the-representation-of-lie-algebra-and-lie-group).