# Representations of general linear Lie algebra vs general linear group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, general-linear-group

I know that $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is not simply connected. Therefore I don’t quite understand the correspondence between representations of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{gl}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. Given a representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ how can i construct a representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$? As I understand in the other direction it could be constructed via exponential map.

Also I would be grateful if someone could recommend some literature on the same topic for different realizations of $\mathfrak{gl}_{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: If $\rho:GL_n(\Bbb C)\rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation, then its differential $d\rho:\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is a Lie algebra representation. See the answer by José Carlos Santos [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316362/what-is-the-relation-between-representations-of-lie-groups-and-lie-algebras). The problem only is that this process will not give **all** Lie algebra representations for $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)$, but you only wanted to "construct **a** representation.

Comment: @Deitrich_Brude Thanks